# ByteCode changes using javassist are not visible in other parts of the code

Tags: java, groovy, javassist

I'm trying to modify the attributes of a java annotation at runtime using javassist library. The changes that I made are visible with javassist but not by other code blocks.

This is the sample groovy script:

```
@Grab(version = "3.20.0-GA", group = "org.javassist", module = "javassist")

import javassist.ClassPool
import javassist.CtClass
import javassist.CtMethod
import javassist.bytecode.AnnotationsAttribute
import javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
import javassist.bytecode.ConstPool
import javassist.bytecode.annotation.StringMemberValue

import java.lang.annotation.*
import java.lang.reflect.Method

@Documented
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RestApiMethod {
    public String description();
}

public class SampleController<T> {
    Class<T> resource

    SampleController(Class<T> resource) {
        this.resource = resource
    }

    @RestApiMethod(description = "Do something on #{ApiClass.name}")
    public void doSomething() {
        println("Dummy Output")
    }
}

public class ModifyAnnotation {

    public static void addRestApiMethodAnnotationToMethod(SampleController controller, Method method,
                                                          String name, String value) {
        //pool creation
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.default
        //get CtClass
        CtClass cc = pool.getCtClass(controller.class.name)
        //looking for the method to apply the annotation on
        CtMethod ctMethod = cc.methods.find { it.name.equals(method.name) }
        // create the annotation
        ClassFile ccFile = cc.classFile
        ConstPool constPool = ccFile.constPool
        javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation annotation = new javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation(RestApiMethod.name, constPool)
        annotation.addMemberValue(name, new StringMemberValue(value, ccFile.getConstPool()))
        // add the annotation
        AnnotationsAttribute attribute = getAnnotationsAttribute(ctMethod)
        System.out.println("Before modification+++++++++++++++++++$attribute")
        attribute.addAnnotation(annotation)
        System.out.println("After modification+++++++++++++++++++$attribute")
        //Write class to file
        cc.writeFile()
        cc.defrost()
    }

    private static AnnotationsAttribute getAnnotationsAttribute(CtMethod ctMethod) {
        return ctMethod.methodInfo.attributes.find { it instanceof AnnotationsAttribute }
    }
}

Closure fetchDoSomethingMethod = {
    SampleController.methods.find { it.name.equals("doSomething") }
}

println(fetchDoSomethingMethod().getAnnotation(RestApiMethod).description())

ModifyAnnotation.addRestApiMethodAnnotationToMethod(new SampleController(Integer), fetchDoSomethingMethod(), "description", "New Value")

println(fetchDoSomethingMethod().getAnnotation(RestApiMethod).description())
```

I have a simple annotation `RestApiMethod` which I'm using on a method inside `SampleController`. When I run this script it prints:

```
Do something on #{ApiClass.name}
Before modification+++++++++++++++++++@RestApiMethod(description="Do something on #{ApiClass.name}")
After modification+++++++++++++++++++@RestApiMethod(description="New Value")
Do something on #{ApiClass.name}
```

and on subsequent executions it prints:

```
Do something on #{ApiClass.name}
Before modification+++++++++++++++++++@RestApiMethod(description="New Value")
After modification+++++++++++++++++++@RestApiMethod(description="New Value")
Do something on #{ApiClass.name}
```

Code inside `ModifyAnnotation.addRestApiMethodAnnotationToMethod` reads updated code, but if I use reflections api to get annotations applied on `doSomething`, it still returns the old value.

Comment: The value may be cached somewhere in java, only direct things can usually be changed.

Comment: I'm writing changes back to file system, that should make the changes permanent and where ever I'm accessing that class in my code should load that changed file. If this is not the case then what could I do to access the changed class to load in rest of my app code.